# Jenkins Pipeline: How to jump to other stages?

Tags: jenkins

There's time that users need to be able to select which stage to jump to instead of the next stage. Can it be done in Jenkins pipeline? For example, after stage one, users can have a choice to select which stage to jump to:

node {
  stage(‘one') {
    sh ‘echo one’
    input 'stage2 | stage3 | stage4'
  }
  stage(’two') {
    sh ‘echo two'
  }
  stage(’three') {
    sh ‘echo three'
  }
  stage(’four') {
    sh ‘echo four'
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in scripted pipeline. I created this in declarative, but it should be easy to reverse engineer this to a scripted pipeline if that is your preference.

Basically, you offer the choice parameter in an input, then use the value to determine if the stage should be run. In a scripted pipeline, you could use an if/then, or a switch statement, or any number of things.

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage ('First') {
            agent any
            steps {
                echo "First dummy stage"
            }
        }
        stage ('Input') {
            agent none
            steps {
                script {
                    myStage = input message: 'What stage do you want to run now?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'Stage1\nStage2\nStage3', description: '', name: 'Stage')]
                }
                echo myStage
            }
        }

        stage('Stage1') {
            when {
                expression { myStage == 'Stage1' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running Stage1"
            }
        }

        stage('Stage2') {
            when {
                expression { myStage == 'Stage2' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running Stage2"
            }
        }

        stage('Stage3') {
            when {
                expression { myStage == 'Stage3' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running Stage3"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using groovy. In your `Jenkinsfile`, you can define conditions at which groovy script will be executed. As a simplified example you can do something as:

```
node {
  if(lint == true) {
    load("lint.groovy").lint()
  }
  if(test == true) {
    load("test.groovy").test()
  }
}
```

In the above example, `lint.groovy` contains a `lint()` function which has the `lint` stage. The same is true with `test.groovy` which defines a `test()` function and a `test` stage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. Here's what I've resolved, I wrapped stages in if...else condition

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'branch name') {
env.DEPLOY_TO_LAST = input message: 'User input required',
        parameters: [choice(name: 'Deploy to LAST', choices: 'no\nyes')]
if (env.DEPLOY_TO_LAST == 'yes'){
    stage('LAST') {
        node('') {
            sh 'echo "stage Last"'
            unstash(name: 'Saved')
        }
    }
}
else {
    stage('FIRST') {
        node('') {
            sh 'echo "stage FIRST"'
            unstash(name: 'Saved')
        }
    }
    stage('SECOND') {
        node('') {
            sh 'echo "stage SECOND"'
            unstash(name: 'Saved')
        }
    }
    stage('THIRD') {
        node('') {
            sh 'echo "stage THIRD"'
            unstash(name: 'Saved')
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. I am using declarative pipeline and I get this error `WorkflowScript: 4: Expected a stage @ line 4, column 1.`

Comment: @anupshrestha try putting a ```script {}``` block around the code you want to execute on line 4